# Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error: Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT

Tags: 22.04, python3, postgresql, error-handling, pgadmin

While trying to launch pgAdmin4, I receive the following error:

```
Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT
```

This is the runtime environment:

```
Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/julien/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS: JS ERROR;JS LOG
  - LC_TIME: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - USER: julien
  - XDG_SESSION_TYPE: wayland
  - SHLVL: 0
  - HOME: /home/julien
  - OLDPWD: /home/julien
  - DESKTOP_SESSION: ubuntu
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop
  - GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
  - GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE: ubuntu
  - LC_MONETARY: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - MANAGERPID: 2723
  - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 409396
  - WAYLAND_DISPLAY: wayland-0
  - LOGNAME: julien
  - _: /usr/bin/gnome-session
  - rvm_bin_path: /usr/share/rvm/bin
  - JOURNAL_STREAM: 8:37688
  - XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
  - USERNAME: julien
  - GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
  - PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin
  - SESSION_MANAGER: local/sunchain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2935,unix/sunchain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2935
  - INVOCATION_ID: b0a4bd7f387b4b94b2d1ad6290b4faa6
  - LC_ADDRESS: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
  - XDG_MENU_PREFIX: gnome-
  - GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY: :1
  - DISPLAY: :0
  - LANG: en_US.UTF-8
  - LC_TELEPHONE: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: ubuntu:GNOME
  - XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: ubuntu
  - XMODIFIERS: @im=ibus
  - XAUTHORITY: /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.OGNI80
  - SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER: gnome-keyring
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
  - LC_NAME: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - SHELL: /usr/bin/zsh
  - QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
  - GDMSESSION: ubuntu
  - rvm_prefix: /usr/share
  - LC_MEASUREMENT: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - LC_IDENTIFICATION: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - rvm_version: 1.29.12 (manual)
  - GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: stderr
  - QT_IM_MODULE: ibus
  - PWD: /home/julien
  - XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
  - LC_NUMERIC: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - LC_PAPER: fr_FR.UTF-8
  - rvm_path: /usr/share/rvm
  - GDK_BACKEND: x11
  - NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 34035
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: dbb4e565-1e23-474d-bd74-c3d8606022cc
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have handle the error to switch pyhton3.10 to python3.9 and error fixed.

Just track the steps:

```
Install python3.9

Switch 3.10 to 3.9
```

You can use the link to do these steps.

https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-python-3-9-or-3-8-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish/

or you just should reinstall pgAdmin4.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. [Laurenz Albe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000900/15589988) to simply reinstall PGAdmin 4 resolved the issue in my case. A downgrade from Python 3.10 to Python 3.9 was not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In my case after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I found that the symbolic link to python whas broken.

To fix that I removed the link and create a new one to the correct path.

`sudo ln -s /path/to/python3.8 /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3`

To know where is python3.8 you can do `which python3.8`, or posibly simply `which python`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same trouble after updating Ubuntu from 22.10 to 23.04.

My winner set of steps was:

- remove pgadmin.
- go to pgadmin's web [site](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/) and setup the repository for my new Ubuntu.

```sh
# Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):
curl -fsS https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg

# Create the repository configuration file:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg] https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

- Install pgadmin

`sudo apt install pgadmin4`

Comment: Happened to me too when upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04. I only needed to do `sudo apt remove pgadmin4-desktop pgadmin4-server` and then reinstall them back - that's it. I initially was worried it will remove the settings and stored DB connections, but everything stayed the same. There was also no need to install the public key, since I already had it from before.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just needed to update the source of pgadmin4 to specific **for my Ubuntu version** in Software & Updates > Other Software from `https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/impish/` to `https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy/`

Comment: this helped, also after a normal upgrade it was still broken, so had to do the following to fix it: `sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop pgadmin4-server --reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I updated the packages after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Save your time and simply reinstall pgAdmin 4

[Link to official doc and follow the simple steps](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/) (mentioned at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

In /usr/pgadmin/venv/bin there are broken shortcuts to python files in /usr/bin/, more precise to python3.8 and python (in my case). To fix these broken links, I just installed python3.8 with the command:

```
sudo apt install python3.8
```

And everything works fine now. Apparently, pgadmin4 looks for these 2 packages and the error occurs because it cannot find them.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the error after running:
`sudo python3 /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py`

In my case, it failed to launch pgadmin 4 because Flask was missing.